# Automorphism Tower

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group. Now consider $\operatorname{Aut} G$ then $\operatorname{Aut} (\operatorname{Aut} G) = \operatorname{Aut}(2G)$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut} G))=\operatorname{Aut}(3G)$ and so on.
>
> Let $n$ be the least positive integer for which $\operatorname{Aut} (nG)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}((n+1)G)$. Find the value of $n$ for the symmetric group of degree $6$ and  explain why it is so. Just use Automorphism in Group theory.

#### Note

1. There is a finite $n$ for finite group.
2. For $S_6$, $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ has index $2$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Also what I have done that for all other symmetric groups of degree $m\ne 6$, $n=0$. But how do I proceed for $m=6$ after getting $[\operatorname{Aut} S_6:\operatorname{Inn} S_6]=2$?

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried so that people are better able to help you.

Comment: Try it. You can see that for a non abelian simple group n=1. Anyway that is much harder to prove. So try to solve it. You may use this result.

Comment: I know this is old, but the answer to this problem follows from looking into the exceptional outer automorphism of $S_6$. $S_6$ is unusual among the symmetric groups for having such an outer automorphism, and as a result, it's automorphism group is larger than itself (unlike the other symmetric groups for $m\geq 3$). The group $Aut(S_6)$ is of order 1440 (twice the size of $S_6$), and it turns out is isomorphic to its own automorphism group (I verified this in GAP). Hence $n=1$.